# Why is my scope, for model with two foreign keys, not working correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have models `Category` and `Transaction`.

`Category has_many transactions`, `Transaction belongs_to category`.

`Transaction` has columns `debit_amount` and `credit_amount`.

I am using a scope that displays categories and sorts them by sum of `transaction.debit_amount` and `transaction_credit_amount`:

```rb
Category.joins(:transactions)
      .where('transactions.created_at >= ?', 1.month.ago)
      .select(
        'categories.*',
        'SUM(transactions.credit_amount_cents + transactions.debit_amount_cents) AS total_amount'
      )
      .order('total_amount DESC')
      .group('categories.id')
      .limit(10)
```

And it works.

Also, I have model `Account`.
Same, `Account has many transactions`, `Transaction belongs_to Account.`

But `Account` has two foreign keys in `Transaction`:

transaction.rb:

```rb
  belongs_to :credit_account, class_name: 'Account',
    foreign_key: 'credit_account_id', optional: true
  belongs_to :debit_account, class_name: 'Account',
    foreign_key: 'debit_account_id', optional: true
```

account.rb:

```rb
  has_many :debit_account_transactions,
    class_name: 'Transaction',
    foreign_key: 'debit_account_id',
    dependent: :nullify
  has_many :credit_account_transactions,
    class_name: 'Transaction',
    foreign_key: 'credit_account_id',
    dependent: :nullify
```

I want to use scope also for accounts. I redid it a bit:

```rb
Account.joins(:credit_account_transactions, :debit_account_transactions)
      .where('transactions.created_at >= ?', 1.month.ago)
      .select(
        'accounts.*',
        'SUM(transactions.credit_amount_cents + debit_account_transactions_accounts.debit_amount_cents) AS total_amount'      )
      .order('total_amount DESC')
      .group('accounts.id')
```

But scope not working correctly :(

For some reason, accounts with `transaction.debit_amount == nil`  are not included in the sample.

UPD.
SQL:

```sql
SELECT accounts.*, 
SUM(transactions.credit_amount_cents + debit_account_transactions_accounts.debit_amount_cents) AS total_amount 
FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "transactions" ON 
"transactions"."credit_account_id" = "accounts"."id" INNER JOIN 
"transactions" "debit_account_transactions_accounts" ON 
"debit_account_transactions_accounts"."debit_account_id" = "accounts"."id" GROUP BY accounts.id
```

Comment: Since this is an inner join it will only include results which have a match in the joined table. Use `.left_join` to create an outer join which will include rows even if there is no row in the joined table.

Comment: @max if i use `left_joins` or `left_outer_joins` accounts wich `transaction.debit_amount == nil` will include in scope, but their `total_amount` will be `0`

Comment: You should probably use `COALESCE(debit_account_transactions_accounts.debit_amount_cents, 0)` to handle potential null values. On most databases NULL +  1 equals NULL not 1 so its still somewhat surprising that you are getting 0 and not NULL. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n29Q8xMyDAdag5cGydH5dD/1